# Given a 3D array (I know my code has 2D array) of dimensions [x][y][z], How do I find the min and max for [][][n] where 0 < n < z Without using Loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, 3d

```js
var people = [
  ["Joe", 27, "US"],
  ["Mark", 34, "UK"],
  ["Alex", 22, "PK"]
];
document.write(people[1][1]);
```

Given a Multidimensional array, How you I find the min and max for `[][][n]` where `0 < n < z` and that Too without using Loops?

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: What does the actual 3d array look like? Can you give an example of input and output?

Comment: @certainPerformance https://owlcation.com/stem/How-to-work-with-Multidimensional-Array-in-C-Programming

Comment: That's not Javascript... again, `Can you give an example of input and output?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd advice you to split the problem in to two parts:

1. Get all the values in the inner (`z`) arrays in to one list using `flatMap`
2. Find the min/max of the resulting list

`flatMap` has many possible implementations. There are even [plans for bringing flatten, with a given depth parameter, to the browser as a standard array feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap).

I'm not sure how strict your "no loops" requirement is, but we'll get to that later. Here's an initial implementation of `flatMap` for 3d arrays using `reduce`, `concat` and `map`.

```
const flatMap = (f, xs) => xs.reduce(
  (acc, ys) => acc.concat(ys.map(zs => f(zs))),
  []
);
```

Call it with a function that retrieves element `n` from `zs` and you got your list of elements:

```
flatMap(zs => zs[1], [ /* .... */ ]); // returns all elements at `n` in the third layer
```

Now, you can apply `Math.min` and `Math.max` by spreading or reducing:

```
const minAge = Math.min(...flatMap(zs => zs[1], [ /* ... */ ]));
```

In a running example:

```js
const data = [
  [
    ["Joe", 27, "US"],
    ["Mark", 34, "UK"]
  ],
  [
    ["Alex", 22, "PK"]
  ]
];

const flatMap = (f, xs) => xs.reduce(
  (acc, ys) => acc.concat(ys.map(f)),
  []
);

// Utils
const max = xs => Math.max(...xs);
const min = xs => Math.min(...xs);
const pluck = k => o => o[k];

const minN = n => d => min(flatMap(pluck(n), d));
const maxN = n => d => max(flatMap(pluck(n), d));

const minAge = minN(1);
const maxAge = maxN(1);

console.log(
  "min age:", minAge(data),
  "max age:", maxAge(data)
)
```

Now, if you're *really* serious about "no loops", I believe the only alternative is recursion. We could rewrite `flatMap` in to something recursive, but it won't necessarily be pretty... If that's what you're looking for, let me know in the comments.